# Need to add digital line

Tags: ringcentral

Few queries are there regarding digital line.
How can digital line be added in Sandbox account and RingCentral phones?
What is actually a digital line and how is it different from a virtual number?
How can be a digital line given to a RingCentral application?
I searched these query all around but didn't got any clear answer or reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the reference :

"A Digital Line is RingCentral's virtual infrastructure assigned to your IP Phone or RingCentral Desktop App for placing outgoing calls. Unlike your Additional Numbers or Virtual Numbers which can only receive incoming calls, a Digital Line can place outbound calls while receiving incoming calls at the same time, just like a regular line. "

ref: https://community.ringcentral.com/questions/20897/digital-line-user-additional-line-clarification.html

You can add Digital line by logging into your RingCentral online portal under `User with extension` section to associate with an extension:

ref:
https://support.ringcentral.com/s/article/ringcentral-phone-softphone-outbound-calling-adding-digital-line?language=en_US